# "Job recommendations" in the "Activity" tab--how to remove?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not sure if this is a new thing, or if I accidentally changed something in my configuration, but I now have "Job recommendations" showing up in my "Activity" tab.  I have them "hidden", but there is still text saying "You've hidden job recommendations", and there is a line beneath that stating how many job recommendations I have.  Is there any way to completely remove this?  I'm not looking for a job, so these are just ads taking up space.

Comment: Looks like you can disable them by selecting "Not interested in jobs" in the "Jobs Match Preferences" in "Edit Profile & Settings".

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, that worked.  I hadn't previously selected any of the options there.

Comment: ["Hidden".](https://kaitlynmcquinheckel.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/princess_bride_that_word.jpg?w=640)

Comment: Use adblock, then block that element

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Job recommendations are shown to all users who have set their job search status to either actively or passively looking. To remove job recommendations, you must set your Job Match preferences to "Not interested in jobs".

[image: Job search status determines if recommendations are shown]

Comment: Thanks.  Mike M. also pointed that out in a comment.  I had never changed that setting, so none of the options were selected.  I guess in that case, you still get the recommendations.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Hmmm.... That sounds like a possible bug. Let me double check that's working correctly.

Comment: @Hynes can confirm: I've never even gone _near_ job stuff on SO, and I got spammed by these job offers. Please don't.

Comment: So the ONLY way to remove is to say not interested.  This is broken.  I am on the activity pages dozens of times a day.  But now you are requiring me to choose between perusing jobs with the occasional email, and removing the monstrosity.  OK, I will turn off the jobs.

Comment: *To remove job recommendations, you must set your Job Match preferences to "Not interested in jobs".* what about users like myself, who are open to being approached by employers but do not want to actively look at 'matches' themselves?

Comment: @Tim haven't you heard? "not looking for a job" is now codeword for "looking for a job" :P

Comment: I don't like this change at all. I don't mind getting job emails once in a while, since I just filter the emails to another folder and look at them when I'm interested. I do mind having the job recommendations in my face every time I go to my activity tab. I too have turned off jobs for now.

Comment: One word: Adblock.

Comment: The "Hide Jobs" button should not just minimise it, but actually hide it, with an option to show it again in job settings. Can it, at the very least, be made non-bold? It's one of 3 (?) bold black texts on the page - drawing that much attention to something that's "hidden" is a bad user experience.

Comment: JJJ: that's three.

Comment: Can I be passively interested without recommendations shoved into where my eyes have been scanning tabs for new activity for the past few years? It feels really shady that you guys put it where you did. If I want to passively look, I'll actively go to the Jobs tab.