# Move "Hidden" job recommendations to bottom of activity page

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, activity-tab

I've "Hidden" job recommendations on the activity page in hopes that it wouldn't take screen real-estate away from the information I want to see. After the job recommendations are hidden, they minimize to a single bar that shows you the number of job recommendations and an option to expand the job recommendations again.

Can this be moved out of view when I opt to hide jobs? Maybe moved to the bottom of the page? I don't want to indicate that I'm [not interested in jobs at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351139/775544), but at the same time moving the information I actually loaded that page to see is a little much.

Something like this would be nice when you opt to hide jobs:[image]

Comment: Yeah, _"Do you want people to AdBlock that div? Because that's how you get people to AdBlock that div"_. Its selector is `##.row.js-jobs-recommendations.activity-recommendations`.

Comment: Or just leave the job recommendations in the side bar where they belong. I don't think they belong on the activity page at all.

Comment: Just an interesting side note here: I have had precisely zero interest in Stack Overflow Jobs and the Developer Story until it started prompting me with job recommendations. Will this new-found interest last? I don't know.

Comment: I had a "NSFW" feeling when that bar popped right in the middle of the screen... at work! At least it could go "bellow the fold" as suggested.

Comment: -1 for moving it to the bottom, +2 for moving it to somewhere that's not where it currently is (ideally to the void).

Comment: Yep it's highly annoying where it is. Especially as there is a delay in loading. A couple of times I've been on my recent activity page and gone to click a link and then suddenly the link moves when it loads and everything gets pushed down.

Comment: The motion is definitely the most annoying aspect.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a userscript you can use to hide that thing.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         removeUnwantedNotificationForJobs
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  make stackoverflow great again!
// @author       You
// @match        *stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    let el = document.getElementsByClassName('activity-recommendations');
    if (el) el[0].style.display = 'none';
})();
```