# Don't let the job recommendations bar loading reflow the activity page

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I am open to messages from potential employers, but I'm not actively seeking them out, therefore I don't want to see job recommendations on my profile. So I'm [not going to say that I'm not interested in jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351143/move-hidden-job-recommendations-to-bottom-of-activity-page).

However, if you *must* display them there, then please rethink their design.

This is how I browse Stack Overflow on mobile:

[image: bloody job recommendations bar]

I have a quite large, high-resolution screen, so this is very well readable for me. I don't want to use the mobile site.

See the bugger circled in red? I inadvertently fat-finger that one at least once a day, because it loads *at least* one whole second after the page is rendered, and on spotty networks even slower. So at the moment I decide I want to press the "responses" or "all actions" tab, the job recommendations bar has loaded in the meantime, pushes the rest of the content down and my finger lands on the jobs bar, expanding it, instead of opening the tab I wanted to press.

I loathe the whole async web as such, which causes pages to shuffle and re-render dozens of times while loading, but hey, it's the future apparently.

Anyway, could you please not load it asynchronously? Or reserve that space already when rendering the page, so the page doesn't shuffle around after while the AJAX responses drizzle in? Or [move it to the bottom](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351143/move-hidden-job-recommendations-to-bottom-of-activity-page)? Anything but the current behavior will be fine.

On my desktop browsers I have blocked the element through uBlock, but on mobile I can't.

Comment: I wonder why recommended jobs can't just have its own unique tab in your user profile. The activity page is not where I would expect to get recommendations, that's where I expect to see my activity :/

Comment: While I don't consider it reasonable to ask for this content to be loaded synchronously, or to delay displaying the rest of the page until that content is available, it is eminently reasonable to have the page layout reserve the space for the jobs at the time the page first loads, prior to loading the ad content. As you've mentioned, your real issue is that the layout moves just as you are interacting with the page. That's bad design, resulting in a bad UX. Just reserving the space would resolve the issue that you are having (as you've mentioned, but your primary request isn't reasonable).

Comment: @Kaiido hell no, no skeleton screens, the most useless invention since loading throbbers. Of course I'd rather have the whole job recommendations bar gone, but that's not the point of this request. I'm also not explicitly asking for it to be loaded synchronously, especially not if that would noticeably slow down that page. I just don't want my activity page to reflow, how Stack Overflow fixes that is up to them.

Comment: @Makyen it already is minimized when I click it, after which it expands.

Comment: @CodeCaster your feature request was explicitly asking for it to be loaded *synchronously*... The skeleton might only be a CSS rule setting a fixed, expected size for the container, no need to make anything fancy. But since your edit, this FR seems more reasonable to me. Mission accomplished for this little comment ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido I simply meant to ask for it not to be loaded asynchronously as currently happens, but I hope my edit clarifies that.

Comment: @CodeCaster well *not loading it asynchronously* means to load it synchronously. Which also means wait for it to have loaded before showing anything else on the page.

Comment: Well there's no reason it can't load asynchronously into an element with a fixed height to avoid the reflow issue