# Job recommendations box in activity page spams users

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, activity-tab

This is a bug report concerning the job recommendations shown in the activity tab, one that is distinct from both ["How to remove them?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351139/job-recommendations-in-the-actvity-tab-how-to-remove) and ["Move them away"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351143/move-hidden-job-recommendations-to-bottom-of-activity-page). I'd love to make this about [the buggy "hide" feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351139/job-recommendations-in-the-actvity-tab-how-to-remove#comment484804_351139) but I suspect that's by design.

My issue is that users who have never enabled any Jobs-specific settings in their profile get job recommendations. According to [a comment of Hynes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351139/job-recommendations-in-the-actvity-tab-how-to-remove#comment484799_351140) this is *not* by design. I would also note that I'd even expect a setting of "*I'm open [to job offers], but I'm not actively looking*" to imply that [the given user isn't looking for jobs, hence doesn't want to see job offers in their profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351139/job-recommendations-in-the-actvity-tab-how-to-remove#comment484905_351140)—but again this is probably by design.

As a user who isn't interested in jobs, not to mention Jobs, having job offers shoved in my face in my own profile page and not even being able to dismiss them with a click feels very much like unsolicited advertising of a service that I'm explicitly not interested in. We usually take spam very seriously on Stack Overflow, so I can only expect the same to apply to this instance.

Comment: I saw it today, was put-off by it, but moved on. SE has to make money somehow and I'd prefer them make it with this type of ad than just about anything else.

Comment: @TecBrat the model, as I see it, is that the community generates the knowledge that leads to traffic and revenue. I'm contributing my share by providing quality content (within my abilities, of course) on the main site; anything else that tries to make money at my expense (in a loose sense of "expense", mostly annoyance in this case) is unwelcome.

Comment: For me the "Hide jobs" link is good enough. It just takes a line there, and it doesn't give additional cognitive burden as the line is quite empty, just a text with "n jobs recommendation", which is perfect for me, someone who is interested, but not actively looking (which means if I stumble on some job ads, I might or might not want to click to see what's it about).

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for the status update and the fix.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading information out of the gate - awful hard to get a clear picture on how something is supposed to work on a Friday afternoon. The implicit behavior here makes sense, but it's awful hard to recognize that it exists when it doesn't actually work - next time hopefully I'll have time to dig up a spec or read the code vs. just poking around in chat.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't think there was any harm done, don't worry about it. You gave a quick workaround, anything else is mostly philosophy and doesn't change much. Anyway I'm glad to hear that this wasn't intended behaviour after all :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:** this was definitely *not* by design. The *intent* here was to show the job matches to folks who'd either **explicitly** said they were looking or interested in jobs, or had filled out some or all of the "job match criteria":

[image: Job Match Preferences section of profile settings]

Roberta found a bug in this check that was *always* causing it to think at least one of these preferences had been set; because of this, even folks who'd never shown any interest at all in Jobs were being shown recommendations (and not necessarily even particularly relevant recommendations, since no matching preferences were set!)

**This is fixed now** - if you never paid any attention to jobs, you should *not* be seeing this on your profile.

If you *have* filled out some of the job match preferences & still don't want to see job recommendations, you can still hide them by setting your Job search status (in the Job Match Preferences section of your profile) to "Not interested in jobs" - this'll hide it regardless of what else you've filled out.

#### See also: [Concerns about (new?) profile settings/preferences related to Jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351279/concerns-about-new-profile-settings-preferences-related-to-jobs/351283#351283)

Comment: Thanks for the real quick response. Sure, disabling it in the profile is not that difficult, I just didn't expect this to be on purpose. The banner came across as strongly intrusive: whoever wants job offers surely has them enabled already... I couldn't help feeling Microsofted by the off-putting experience. I'm also skeptical about the validity of the signal that is made up of people explicitly disabling jobs in their profile: who is to say whether this is due to the banner being annoying and not something else? Anyway, I'll just disable it and see the end of it.

Comment: The SO user profile just seems like a *really* stupid place for jobs to go. If I'm interested in seeing jobs targeted at me, I'll click on the "Jobs" tab. (Which, probably not coincidentally, has been recently renamed.) Are you guys really having that big of a problem with people ignoring the Jobs site? Maybe putting more annoying things in peoples' faces isn't the right answer to cash-flow problems...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not totally clear on the rationale here @cody; I suspect it's less folks not finding the job site and more not finding the Story tab (or not figuring out what it's for) - see also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349769/profile-developer-story-usability-findings

Comment: I've *found* the Story tab, and I'm trying my hardest to avoid it. My concerns have been expressed multiple times on Meta by plenty of other users, including in the link you cited, but there has been little effort to address them. This lack of this is becoming a disturbing theme around here. Cramming things down users' throats is not an especially appealing business model.

Comment: @Cody as long as actual expert users stick around, the business model works. But there's a reason many users have been more and more snarky when anything concerning the "community-centered" nature of SO has came up. What the community thinks is in no way a primary concern.

Comment: Are all these job-related settings new to the profile preferences page? I am 100% positive I never signed up for any of this, and yet when I went to my profile after reading this answer, I saw an entire section of jobs-related e-mails with the checkboxes checked! Opt-out-style spam tactics are really unlike Stack Overflow.

Comment: These adverts keep telling me things like: you have to move to Germany, learn German and Javascript. I don't want to move to Germany, it is far away. In fact, I don't want to move at all. I don't want to learn German and I'm clueless about Javascript. In fact, I'm not even interested in job offers in the first place! Seems like [spam-by-design] to me...

Comment: You wanna make a separate post about that, @TylerH? With a screenshot? There are, apparently, two different email preferences UIs in use right now, and I'm not clear on which one you're looking at.

Comment: @Shog9 Done: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351279/concerns-about-new-profile-settings-preferences-related-to-jobs

Comment: Yeah, I'm not wild about that choice either @davidism; I know Hynes has been doing some thinking on a better UI - wanna post a separate feature-request for such an option?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken [this feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352290/can-we-stop-showing-jobs-on-the-profile-activity-page-please) asks for exactly that, cc @davidism.