# Concerns about (new?) profile settings/preferences related to Jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page

If you want a tl;dr, scroll to the bottom, below the line break.

I recently visited my profile page and was surprised by a new Jobs ad:

[image: job ads in the activity tab]

Having *never* participated in anything Jobs related on Stack Overflow, I was a little miffed at having this injected, to be honest. Especially smack dab in the flow of the page, rather than at the top or along the side bar, where such annoying advertisements have long been relegated here at Stack Overflow.

I clicked "Hide jobs", which only *sort of* hides them:

[image: "hidden" jobs ads]

(It would be great if clicking "hide jobs" hid the whole element instead of minimizing it, so that I don't have to `display: none` that element via a custom style)

A little alarmed, I went looking on Meta for an announcement for this, and  [Job recommendations box in activity page spams users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351196/job-recommendations-box-in-activity-page-spams-users) caught my eye first. After reading Shog's answer, I learned that there are apparently some settings you can turn off. Confident that I would never have turned these things on to begin with, or that I had already turned them off, I went looking, and was really surprised to see an *entire section of job preferences*, ***all enabled***:

[image: jobs email preferences]

Granted, these are all about e-mail preferences. Still, disturbing that they're checked by default. I'm not sure if there was ever an announcement about this batch of opt-out settings being added.

At any rate, Shog wasn't sure if we were looking at the same settings, so I went over to the Job Match preferences page (the likeliest candidate for these new ads), and here's where I am sitting:

[image: job match preferences]

As you can see, I've never even checked any of these buttons, which appears to be the default state (I don't think I've seen this before now, but I haven't been looking regularly). After clicking the "Not interested" radio button, the HTML element containing the Job Recommendations went away completely, which is good. However, that brings me to the feature request:

---

Can we please update the Job Recommendations feature so that it uses the "Not interested in jobs" behavior (E.g. No job rec advertisements) if none of the radio buttons in "Job match preferences" are selected? It seems like a bit of an oversight, given that the radio buttons don't have an active one by default.

Perhaps the best solution is to just mark everyone as "not interested" if they don't have a radio button selected currently?

Comment: As Shog says in the linked post: *I'm... Not entirely convinced this is a great UX; my gut feeling is that we'd prefer folks who are passively interested to, uh, remain passively interested, and just get the unnecessary line off of the profile.*

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure I agree with that viewpoint; it's taking the long-since debunked "silence is acquiescence" stance.

Comment: @TylerH: no, it is not. Shog9 is saying that he wants to not spam people that are not actively interested.

Comment: @TylerH: I am getting the impression he's just choosing his words carefully, not going 'man, I need to go stalk over to the jobs people and go shout at them for a while'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hmm, I interpreted his comment opposite: that passive interest meant people who might be interested but haven't weighed in either way in the profile settings, therefore they are a silent signal (or no signal, to put it simply) to the dev team. The dev team is currently interpreting no signal as a "yes, I'm interested". This is the point of the question. The crux of the issue is perhaps that this set of radio buttons doesn't have a default option picked. Setting default to opt-in or opt-out would be simpler and more logical than leaving it unset entirely, and then assuming.

Comment: There's another wrench to this whole deal, which is that we're currently testing a much clearer UI for the email preferences. You're *not* in the test, but for some reason when I look at your profile it renders it as though you were - so I greatly appreciate the screenshot, since I wasn't sure what you were talking about otherwise.

Comment: And *on that note*... If I'm looking at this right, those jobs email preferences are mostly just a fine-grained way of representing three options: announcements (been there for a long time, opt-out) Job notifications (irrelevant unless you're actively using Jobs) and Job Search Alerts (again irrelevant unless you've actively subscribed to one or more of those). The UI makes it look like you're gonna get a ton of emails, but in reality you shouldn't get anything in most of those categories unless you're actually using Jobs - the Q&A equiv would be Inbox, Newsletters, Bounties, Tag Filters, etc.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks, that clears up a lot. I *am* in the new questions view beta; perhaps there's some unintentional code tied together between that beta and the email preference beta?

Comment: Not pretending to have the full picture on this by any means; asking around trying to find out more.

Comment: For user testing, employees were temporarily opted into the new email preference screen unconditionally...this was just removed in the latest build and it turned into a normal alpha feature. We're tweaking some copy and then this will be rolling out to improve prefs for all users. @TylerH this whole thing was unintentional - a fix is going out to remove it from users who have shown *zero interested* in jobs. A check unintentionally thought you had set job preferences earlier. Answer incoming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We started showing job recommendations to all users who had ever set a job matching preference, except those who were *not looking for a job*. Unintentionally, however, one of said job matching preferences was marked `true` by default: including your current location on the list of cities you'd like to work.

[image: always set to true, no user action needed]

This has now been fixed and we will no longer show jobs recommendations to users who have never interacted with job preferences or expressed interest in jobs.

Comment: Please also hide them from those that are passively interested. You put a huge section that I'm not actively interested in right in the line that my eyes are trained to scan for tab activity that I'm interested in.

Comment: @davidism Thanks for the feedback. We're still looking into the UX for this and are discussing ways to make it less intrusive.