# Don't show job ads if I'm not interested in jobs

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

In my settings I've selected `Not interested in jobs`

[image]

but I keep seeing ads about Python jobs

[image]

Is this intended? Why show me jobs if I'm not interested in one?

Comment: I don't see the text box saying anything about not showing you any ads if you're not looking...it won't add you to searches, but ads aren't mentioned explicitly.

Comment: What ads would you like to see? Something has to give between you not wanting to see job ads and SO limiting itself to *relevant* advertisement for monetization purposes.

Comment: @Ihazkode are there no other ads in SO? Only jobs?

Comment: @Ihazkode:  There really isn't much "give" given that [Stack Overflow is perfectly fine with you using ad blockers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/).

Comment: I didn't know that @Makoto, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Use a user stylesheet or script and remove that box (it has an id of "hireme").

Comment: I believe any ad-blocker (I use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm) will do the trick by default. I was curious about why this was happening before I knew that SO did not care about us using ad-blockers.

Comment: Ads pay the bills... don't you think is a small price for everything stackoverflow gives to you?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi [you're putting the cart before the horse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351196/job-recommendations-box-in-activity-page-spams-users#comment485423_351196). Let the unregistered and 1-rep noobs generate income. It's the contributors who create the content that draws in traffic. That being said, I'm not particularly bothered by job ads on the right, but I do shake my head when they have nothing to do with my tags.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi GOTO comment 4

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't about to just stop showing you ads, but it would make sense for them to show a regular display ad instead of a jobs ad.

Comment: It's still a brand advertisement. Think of it as SO advertising you can look for jobs on them for when you are looking for jobs.

Comment: There only **two ways** a site of this magnitude can exist in the long run. 1- By **displaying ads**. 2- by **hording all your data** and selling them to companies that use that data to display ads. We can all pretend to live in wonderland and say SO is fine with Adblock but the truth is... **if everyone used Adblock SO wouldn't last long** unless it starts hording usage data which includes your neighbor's second cousin's favorite color. These are the overly general ramblings of someone with very basic understanding of how things like this work. Feel free to disagree but don't expect a debate.

Comment: @Ihazkode Yes, *personalized* ads. And if I say "I'm not looking for a job," then showing me job ads is not a good idea, because I'm less likely to click them. StackOverflow could make more money by showing relevant ads. After all, Google lets you choose what ads you see: https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/1631343?hl=en

Comment: Forgive me if my point was not clear. My point is that SO's *relevant* ads policy is **flawed**. There's only so much *relevant* content that companies are willing to pay good monies to promote.  As a result you get very valid complaints from users as highlighted by OP. "I clearly stated that I'm not looking for a job...why are you showing me this?" That on top of the self-imposed limits on income. *Outsource* the ads altogether. I'm sure Google would be happy to oblige by any "special requests" SO makes for what sort of ads are to be displayed on SO pages..but hey, that's another can of worms

Comment: I am currently set as "not looking for job" because I am not interested in being contacted for a job. But seeing randomly what job is available still interest me. For me, the current situation is fine.

Comment: @ihazkode, outsource the ads to Google? Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/08/06/podcast-64/)? They have tried, and the effectiveness was miserable.

Comment: I think this post got a bit side-tracked from its original point. I did not ask to *stop seeing ads*, it was just a request for more custom tailored ads. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the fact of ad blockers, which are always playing cat and mouse with revenue providers anyway, Stack Exchange has a broad range of sites to distribute all their third party interests to. The [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) has an above par clause of not sharing user data with third parties that don't share the *same* privacy policy, not just trusting they have their own.

Now, there are other reasons for wanting ads out of our way, such as screen estate or distractions. Perhaps it just looks less professional in your workplace.  There is a certain perk for users who sign up and acrue a reputation 200:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads
Can you guess what that does? I certainly wasn't expecting it when reaching that threshold but it represents a balance point. The reduced-ads priviledge page states:

> We want to emphasize that you should only re-enable banner ads if you want to see them, not because you're trying to support us financially.

It also states that side bar ads stay, but we're used to ignoring the side bar anyway, right?

In user preferences you may notice a button to <kbd>[Manage personalized predictions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data)</kbd> which allows you to download your stored data or opt in / out of predictions. Amongst the piles of random words there it's made clear:

> It is not used to help other websites sell you pants, based on your interest in pant-based technologies here.

Huh. So your aggregated data is used to make *jobs* more relevant, *not* tracked advertising. Kind of makes me wish I was looking for a job. But in conjunction with the privacy policy it also means that anywhere that tracks customers outside of the site, aggregates interactions with Stack Exchange partners, or tries to use our precious Data Explorer against us, has the wrath of Jon Skeet to reckon with.

Answer (score -6):

Look, dear fellow SO community. If we don't pay for the product we *are* the product. That's a hard reality.

There's no magic that makes electricity free for StackOverflow, or means their people don't need health insurance and all that.  Our friends who operate StackOverflow have to pay their bills somehow. From where I sit they also deserve to make a decent profit.

They've done as well as any web property could possibly do at building an advertising system that's friendly to their product (that's us) and to their advertisers.

Plus, often the best candidate for a particular job is already happily employed. Hiring managers want to entice those folks. I'd much rather have my co-workers see ads on SO than get a lot of cold calls from recruiters.

If there were a way for me to pay for the product so I didn't have to *be* the product, I might consider it. A subscription fee might be helpful. But unless and until that happens, with respect we need to let SO pursue their business.

Comment: Of course we are the product. You have nearly 50k rep, suggesting that you are, like me, one of the drones generating the high-quality answers that attract people to this website. Obviously we don't need to pay for the product; *we are the ones providing the service*!