# Method to prevent opening in Developer Story

Tags: support, bug, status-planned, developer-story, login

I have chosen not to provide a great deal of information about myself in my profile and I have selected, not interested in Jobs. However, Stack Overflow seems determined to gain information about me.

Recently, every time I log in, I am presented with the "Developer Story" page.

Is there any way to turn this annoying "feature" off and return to being presented with the "Questions" page, which is how it worked formerly?

As requested here is a screen shot
[image: Initial screen on logging in]

Comment: If this is an actual "feature" rather than something going wrong somewhere, that's... and I hate to say it... LinkedInny. Yuck!

Comment: That's probably a bug. Would you like to see some jobs in the mean time?

Comment: I have literally nothing in my profile (I don't even have the Autobiographer badge), I don't have a dev story page, but if I log in in a private window I see the front page. So I think I can't reproduce. Using 45.9 Firefox on Debian.

Comment: I don't see the behaviour you report.... do you log in via a bookmark? Seems too obvious but worth a try :P

Comment: @Clonkex I log in using the "Log In" button, not via a bookmark. The login is via google, although I do not know if it is germane but the damned thing just happened again. It's only an extra click to move on but it's annoying.

Comment: Maybe provide more information, like the complete url on which you are before login, the exact url on which you land after, ...

Comment: don't you understand, these boring questions and answers aren't a priority anymore. New vision is all about [Developer Affinity & Growth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351751/839601). (sarcasm aside, showing dev story _once_ would probably make good sense as a means to introduce it to folks who don't know about this recent feature. But only once)

Comment: @gnat - I'm not sure what you mean, but the post you've linked to says that that team *does* handle "these boring questions and answers", for example the *ask question* page.

Comment: No, that button is getting removed in the next iteration @Kobi :)

Comment: What about using an adblocker and blocking the element?

Comment: Give us a screenshot, maybe we're thinking of something other than what you're seeing.

Comment: He's probably talking about the developer story ad at the top you need to dismiss.  Screen shot it please.

Comment: Ah, so you _do_ have a developer story, and it's public, but barely no information there. Have you tried turning it private (I mean the obvious link on the right)? I could see why SO would badger you to edit it: the whole (?) point (?) of developer story is to be a funky new public display of your achievements (?)

Comment: @AndrasDeak: That's not a good enough reason to slap us in the face with it all the time. Not all of us are open source whizzkids who want to / _can_ advertise all our achievements in public. Some of us are actual professionals in the real world ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sure, most of my point was (albeit not conveyed very clearly) that it's no wonder that I can't reproduce OP's issue without a dev story. If you have it disabled (like you do), you probably won't see this if you log in (as I don't either). I suspect this to be coupled with OP's public-yet-empty dev story page. Of course it's still unclear whether it's a bug or a feature, and I'm with you regarding the reception if it's the latter.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony show us the full URL inside of the bookmark you use to access StackOverflow (or the login page you go to).

Comment: @AndrasDeak   No, but if you keep bombarding me with job offers while on my work computer, I might need to see some job offers.

Comment: By tightly coupling something I use on a daily basis on my job (programmer Q&A) with something I'd never do even indirectly on employer owned hardware (job search); SO has guaranteed that I'll never use their service while employed.  (And without being certain there's a permanent off button available, probably wouldn't even if I become unemployed at some point in the future.)

Comment: @DanNeely if you read OP's self-answer, you'll see that no one is being harassed with dev story if they click the right login link. Now, your concerns could be more appropriate [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351801/dont-show-job-ads-if-im-not-interested-in-jobs) (although you could use adblock for that). If your work involves a lot of SO, your employer should find it appropriate that you're using SO...

Comment: @AndrasDeak I was snarkily responding to your initial snarky comment, and while my employer's fine with my using SO for QA I don't want messages from recruiters/etc showing up either as notices on the SO topbar or in any of the email accounts linked to my SO profile.  My resume/linked in/etc all use a separate address that I've never accessed from a work computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I think that I have cracked it.
After turning the developer profile private, disabling email notifications and turning off all "Job Emails" (didn't know they even existed) to no avail.
It appears that it was the link that I was using to login.
Until recently the login page looked like this.

[image: original login]

Using this to login avoids this really annoying ´Developer Story` first page.

The latest login page that I see is this

[image: latest login page]

If I click on the Google link in this page, I see the `Developer Story` page.
If I click on the `Login` at the top right, I see the first (original) login page and every thing is fine.
Quite why there is a difference I have no idea.
If I'd wanted to look for a job, I would have signed up with a job agency, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Now that you've successfully logged in would you like a job?

Comment: "Would you like to add 'successful log-in' to your developer story?"

Comment: Well, that giant blue area is technically a huge banner ad talking about jobs (see the bit at the bottom that says "stack overflow business solutions"?). So it kinda makes sense that the login button inside that giant blue area would take you to the *jobs* portion of the site. Definitely annoying, but that's the reason.

Comment: Ah, so I couldn't reproduce your issue because I was using the wrong (right) link.

Comment: So you've been using the "sign up for new account using google credentials" all along, and at some point the system pulls up the already-associated account instead of making a new empty one, but still takes you through the signup survey?  Seems legit.

Comment: @BenVoigt I didn't even realize that the whole blue box was _supposed_ to correspond to "sign up", but the blue highlight of the sign-up button up top probably suggests this. This is horrible UX.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: It's the "Sign Up" button below that tells you this, not the one above.  The structure is "Identify yourself by (linking a Google or Facebook account or filling in the form) then (sign up)".  Not "(login using Google or Facebook) or (sign up by filling in the form)".  Compare to every shopping cart page ever that has Paypal/Visa Checkout/Google Wallet/Amazon Pay buttons.  They provide an alternative to filling in the checkout form, but they still initiate a checkout procedure, and are not functionally equivalent to the login page (even if they may also leave you logged in).

Comment: @Andras: The wording "join the community" to the left also leads to the conclusion that the whole banner is a signup / account creation, not login.

Comment: @RickAstley It's rare that a comment makes me laugh out loud :)

Comment: @DavidThomas and unheard of to have 2 comments that make me spit my drink out :)

Comment: @RolfofSaxony This is an unintended consequence of our new inline sign up form. There were really two problems.
1. We didn't intend existing users to sign in using this form (cool that it works).
2. There is a bug that sends you to the dev story instead of the home page.

We will fix the bug no later than next week. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @JoeFriend Nice to know the reason. That's the trouble with "users" they always click stuff that wasn't in the test suite ;)

Comment: @JoeFriend this behaviour is still present as far as I can tell, any update on this?