# Can we stop showing jobs on the profile activity page, please?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs

Recently, job recommendations were added to the activity tab in the profile page. This is quite annoying, as I don't want to read it all the time.

[image: "Job Recommendations" from profile page]

Also, I've set my preferences as I am not actively looking for jobs but kinda open to new opportunities. Changing it to "Not Interested" doesn't hide this panel either (I expected it would hide if I switched to this option).

Is there any way I can hide it? I don't want to just minimize them, either. I want to remove this panel altogether.

Or, can we at least change it in such a way that it only shows up for the people who are actively looking for the jobs? It doesn't add any value for other users, and it eats up a good amount of space.

Comment: Just to prevent future mishaps: This question is **not** a duplicate of ["Job recommendations” in the “Activity” tab--how to remove?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351139/job-recommendations-in-the-activity-tab-how-to-remove?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: *Changing it to "Not Interested" doesn't hide this panel either.* - Shouldn't this be tagged as a bug then?

Comment: @BSMP I am not sure if such a feature even exists so. Also, I don't want to switch it to *Not Interested* just to hide that panel. That will be bad if someone is checking out my dev story and it shows up as not interested over there.

Comment: I get that you also want it gone if you're not actively looking but it not working at all sounds like a bug. it should have worked the way you expected it to when you switched it to Not Interested, according to the post rene linked to.

Comment: @BSMP hmmm, when I checked that post, I got confused.. cuz it says that it hides if we select Not Interested but ignored then..

Comment: A user script to remove is here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351234/7311767

Comment: Setting "Not interested" should disable these ads [as per my bugreport, now fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351196/job-recommendations-box-in-activity-page-spams-users), so that part of the question should be a bug report (assuming that I understand correctly). Shog [essentially said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351196/job-recommendations-box-in-activity-page-spams-users?#comment485811_351198) that *passively* interested people get these job ads by design, but he's not personally convinced that this is a good thing. I linked this feature-request on his post there.

Comment: _Actually_, explicitly setting "not interested" worked to begin with; my bug report was about handling users with no existing preference.

Comment: This site is used by professionals in settings where we commonly share screens with each other. I would be uncomfortable using the site if my job search preferences (either way) could be infered by my colleagues. Please do not link my job search preferences (which I consider confidential) with how the main site displays to me.