# Give the Jobs panel on profile page a fixed height so it doesn't reflow page

Tags: bug

Leaving aside [whether the jobs panel should even be shown on the profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352290/can-we-stop-showing-jobs-on-the-profile-activity-page-please), it's really irritating that currently it causes a page reflow a second or so after the main page loads. That makes it hard to click on the stuff that I actually came to the page for.

Just give the panel a fixed height.