# "Job recommendations" makes position jump

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page

On my profile I'm shown "job recommendations" as my job search status is shown as active.

[image]

Nothing wrong with that as such, but it won't load until 2 seconds after the page, making everything below it jump down.

This is really annoying. The page should load with something like `<div height="200px" id="job-recommendations"></div>` (as is [already done with the advertisements if you have <200 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168943/everyone-loves-stack-overflow/168945)).

Related:

- [“Job recommendations” in the “Activity” tab--how to remove?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351139/660921)
- [Move “Hidden” job recommendations to bottom of activity page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351143/move-hidden-job-recommendations-to-bottom-of-activity-page)